# Custom drl operator not working in Drools 7.71 when upgrading from 7.31

Tags: drools

We create what is essentially a custom operator called `contains_any` with a definition that implements `org.drools.core.base.evaluators.EvaluatorDefinition`. It was working in 7.31 at the latest that I am aware of. Has the api for registering a new evaluator definition changed?

We are registering the custom definition:

```
kieServices.newKieModuleModel().setConfigurationProperty("drools.evaluator.contains_any", ContainsAnyDefinition.class.getName());`
```

Compiling the DRL now results in:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Build Errors: Error Messages: Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rule1.drl, line=18, column=0 text=[ERR 102] Line 18:41 mismatched input 'contains_any' in rule "rule1" in pattern] Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rule1.drl, line=0, column=0 text=Parser returned a null Package]
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.